# Refresh a screen after a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I currently have several if statements that populate a specific table after the button refresh has been clicked.

After the button is clicked again I need to remove the previous table that is polulated. How can I do that?

```
if (strDate == "Jan-2010") {
    var TableRowHtml = "<table id='box-table-a'>";
    TableRowHtml +="<TR><TH 'style='width: 50px'>OPERATIONS</TH></TR>";
    TableRowHtml +="<TR><TH 'style='width: 50px'>Unit Costs</TH></TR>";
    TableRowHtml +="<TR><TD>" + Total[0] + "</TD></TR>";
}
else if (strDate == "Feb-2010") {
    var TableRowHtml1 = "<table id='box-table-a'>";
    TableRowHtml1 +="<TR><TH 'style='width: 50px'>OPERATIONS</TH></TR>";
    TableRowHtml1 +="<TR><TH 'style='width: 50px'>Unit Costs</TH></TR>";
    TableRowHtml1 +="<TR><TD>" + Total[1] + "</TD></TR>"; 
}
else if (strDate == "Mar-2010") {
    var TableRowHtml2 = "<table id='box-table-a'>";
    TableRowHtml2 +="<TR><TH 'style='width: 50px'>OPERATIONS</TH></TR>";
    TableRowHtml2 +="<TR><TH 'style='width: 50px'>Unit Costs</TH></TR>";
    TableRowHtml2 +="<TR><TD>" + Total[2] + "</TD></TR>"; 
}
else if (strDate == "Apr-2010") {
    var TableRowHtml3  = "<table id='box-table-a'>";
    TableRowHtml3 +="<TR><TH 'style='width: 50px'>OPERATIONS</TH></TR>";
    TableRowHtml3 +="<TR><TH 'style='width: 50px'>Unit Costs</TH></TR>";
    TableRowHtml3 +="<TR><TD>" + Total[3] + "</TD></TR>"; 
}
```

Dropdown code:

```
<tr><td><select id="combobox">
      <option value="Jan-2010">Jan/2010</option>
      <option value="Feb-2010">Feb/2010</option>
      <option value="Mar-2010">Mar/2010</option>
      <option value="Apr-2010">Apr/2010</option>
      <option value="May-2010">May/2010</option>
      <option value="Jun-2010">Jun/2010</option>
  </select></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="RefreshMetrics"  value="Refresh"></td>
</tr>
</select></td>
<td><input type="button" id="RefreshMetrics"  value="Refresh"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Can place the below code in each specfic if statement e.g... remove each table that is not needed ... for that paticular month

```
                      if (strDate == "Jan-2010") 

                    {


                   $('TableRowHtml1').last().remove();
                   $('TableRowHtml2').last().remove();
                   $('TableRowHtml3').last().remove();



       var TableRowHtml = "<table id='box-table-a'>";     
       TableRowHtml +="<TR><TH 'style='width: 50px'>OPERATIONS</TH></TR>";           
 TableRowHtml +="<TR><TH 'style='width: 50px'>Unit Costs</TH></TR>";                   TableRowHtml +="<TR><TD>" + Total[0] + "</TD></TR>";     
                }
```

Comment: @Gilles why do you re-included the (obviously accidentally) double-pasted `</select></td>` and the button? That's invalid HTML.

Comment: @feela because I'm wary of changing code in questions, other than whitespace (when it's clearly irrelevant). I wasn't confident enough that the HTML was a copy-paste error. ＠MarkSull I don't know how you're doing your copy-pastes, but please indent your posts properly (4 spaces to distinguish code from text, then consistent code intentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery remove API.

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

`$('table').last().remove();`

Comment: Hi Madhur, i have edited my above code and placed the .remove API in a the If statement for month "Jan". Is this correct ?

Comment: The jquery selector $('TableRowHtml2') is wrong, you need to select either based on id such as '#box-table-a' or the tag name 'table'